# What data type is STRUCT in java?

Tags: java, arrays, type-conversion

I saw a already written old java code today which had these lines:

```
  STRUCT accDetail = new STRUCT(t_account_details, conn, itemAttributes);
  STRUCT[] accDetails = {accDetail};
```

What kind of Datatype is this STRUCT ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It's just an ordinary Java class that someone picked a weird name for. See if you have any documentation for it or if your IDE recognizes it, because it's unlikely anyone seeing your question will know about this class.

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/905/jdbc-javadoc/oracle/sql/STRUCT.html

Comment: @NomanK Good find. Is there an import in the code of that class?

Answer (score 1):

In this context `STRUCT` appears to be a badly named class. Classes are normally named as follows:

"Class names should be nouns, in mixed case with the first letter of each internal word capitalized. Try to keep your class names simple and descriptive. Use whole words-avoid acronyms and abbreviations (unless the abbreviation is much more widely used than the long form, such as URL or HTML)."

See [Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367) for more information.

As per the comment from Noman K see (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/sql/STRUCT.html#STRUCT_oracle_sql_StructDescriptor__java_sql_Connection__java_util_Map_)

```
public STRUCT(StructDescriptor type,
              java.sql.Connection conn,
              java.lang.Object[] attributes)
       throws java.sql.SQLException

    Constructor. The raw bytes are computed at this time or a copy of attributes is made. In any event the caller is free to modify the array without affecting the values held in the STRUCT. For inherited object types we must check that the descriptor indicates that the type is instantiable. That database does not check on e.g. insertion but only on PL/SQL object creation. So we have to check here, too. There is an argument to be made that there is a good use for the STRUCT instance to carry data around and that the error ought to be when an insertion or udpate is attempted. But this keeps the "not instantiable" rather than "not storable" notion. And is is much more simple.

    Parameters:
        type - the SQLStructType used to convert the type to
        attributes - the array specifying the attributes to be converted to raw bytes.
    Throws:
        java.sql.SQLException
    See Also:
        oracle.sql.SQLStructType
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the code snippet

```
STRUCT accDetail = new STRUCT(t_account_details, conn, itemAttributes);
  STRUCT[] accDetails = {accDetail};
```

STRUCT is of type STRUCT, though it dosent follow that Java Naming Convention. STRUCT was instantiated with the new keyword and STRUCT constructor which made it obvious that it is a class and all classes in Java is of type the Name they represent. eg. String class is of type String, Date class is of type Date etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are you using an IDE, such as Eclipse, then just click on STRUCT and press F3. It will bring the class definition, which you can use to find out what the class is.

But in any case, this won't be like c++.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [`STRUCT`](http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/905/jdbc-javadoc/oracle/sql/STRUCT.html) Javadoc,

> 1. It is the Oracle implementation class for the generic JDBC Struct interface.
> 2. It wraps the "raw bytes" of an Oracle Object Type.

Java uses this for interacting with an Oracle relational database instance through JDBC. Per the Oracle documentation: [Working with Oracle Object Types](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/java.920/a96654/oraoot.htm#1039477)

> If you choose not to supply a custom Java class for your SQL-Java mapping for an Oracle object, then Oracle JDBC will materialize the object as an instance of the oracle.sql.STRUCT class.